# how can I use a function which is located inside a service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

What I am trying to do is to use function globally throughout controllers.
The problem is when I want to use the function I defined inside the service in the **first** function. It shows an error that *it cannot find a function*. I tried without **this** keyword but it's not working. I can go to **all** function when I tried in other controllers, which is a good sign that I can use this service globally.

*In short, I want to use **all** function inside **first** function.*

```
app.factory("UserService", function() {
  var users = ["Peter", "Daniel", "Nina"];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return users;
    },
    first: function() {
      var users = this.all(); 
      return users[0];
    }
  };
});
```

The code above was an example that I made and real code appears like this. 
**controller**

```
angular.module("app").requires.push("app.region");
```

I put the region to app so I can use the service. 
After that I made a controller like this

```
.controller("regionCreateController", ["$scope", "phoneMaskService", function ($scope, phoneMaskService) {
    $scope.createClicked = function (data) {
        data = phoneMaskService.putMaskOnRegion(data);
        console.log(data);

    };
}
```

When I put *phoneMaskService* which is the service I made in the *app.js* and it fails.

This is the error I am getting

```
angular.js:14110 ReferenceError: removeAllLetters is not defined
```

---

This is the actual code making errors.

```
        .factory("phoneMaskService", [function () {


            var returnMethod = {
                removeAllLetters: removeAllLetters,
                putMaskOn: putMaskOn,
                putMaskOnRegion: putMaskOnRegion
            }; 

            return returnMethod;
            function removeAllLetters(value) {
                var val = value.replace(/\D+/g, '').replace('\-', '');
                return val;
            }
            function putMaskOn(value) {
                console.log(value);
                value = this.removeAllLetters(value);
                console.log(value);
                var isMobile = parseInt(value.charAt(1)) == 2;
                if (isMobile) {
                    var x = value.replace(/\D/g, '').substring(0, 14).match(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3,})/);
                    x = ' ( ' + x[1] + ' ) ' + x[2] + ' - ' + x[3];
                    return x;
                } else {
                    var x = value.replace(/\D/g, '').substring(0, 14).match(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3,})/);
                    x = ' ( ' + x[1] + ' ) ' + x[2] + ' - ' + x[3];
                    return x;
                }
            }
            function putMaskOnRegion(object) {
                angular.forEach(object, function (value, key) {
                    if (key == "contactNumberPhone") {
                        var testvalue = this.removeAllLetters(value);
                        console.log(this);
                        console.log("test value" + testvalue);
                        object[key] = this.removeAllLetters(value);
                    }  
                });
                return object;
            }

        }])
```

The error happens the line here and says *removeallletters are undefined*

```
 var testvalue = this.removeAllLetters(value);
```

Comment: Where is your controller code?

Comment: controller is working fine because i can register service and use **first** function and when I debug it, it goes inside first function but after encounter **all** function, it says **undefined**.

Comment: I ask for your controller code, because the code you supplied works fine: https://codepen.io/shaunetobias/pen/zYGppwZ

Comment: The code you have should work fine if you are using it normally. There can be binding problems if you pass those functions to other objects. We would need to see the controller code to know what is going wrong.

Comment: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/why-function-bind-matters-little-in-angular/
This documentations I think explains what I have done wrong I guess.

Comment: Review [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). Without a [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is hard to understand what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to avoid binding problems is to declare the functions inside the factory:

```
app.factory("UserService", function() {
  var users = ["Peter", "Daniel", "Nina"];

  return { all: all, first: first };

  function all() {
      return users;
  }

  function first() {
      var users = all(); 
      return users[0];
  }

});
```

Comment: This worked and when I restart application it doesn't work . lol

Comment: Without a [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is hard to understand what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I use the follwoing when declaring factories, which 
creates an object within the factory declaration, binds methods to it and returns is as the the factory object.This might work in your case.

```
app.factory("UserService", function() {
  var services = {};

  services.users = ["Peter", "Daniel", "Nina"];

  services.all = function() {
      return services.users;
  }

  services.first = function() {
      return services.all()[0]; 
  }
 return services;
});
```